# In Django 3 how do I access my templates-directory using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, django, ajax

Maybe I am going about this the wrong way. I want to replace the content of the `<nav>`-element using `jQuery.load()` when the user clicks a certain `<div>`. But I am unable to access the html-file that I want to replace the content with. No matter what url I point the load to, the console always says: `"GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/templates/nav_form.html 404 (Not Found)"`

My Javascript (jQuery) is:

```
jQuery( '#EditIcon' ).on( 'click', function(){
    jQuery( 'nav' ).load( 'templates/nav_form.html' )
});
```

So in the example I use the url `templates/nav_form.html`. When I replace this with `../templates/nav_form.html` or `./templates/nav_form.html` the message in the console remains the same telling me he cannot find `http://127.0.0.1:8000/templates/nav_form.html`

Comment: I think you need to define a url that returns that template and then use that url to get the template and load it however you want to. If the html file is static and is not being used by a url, you can keep it in the static folder and add static url and load it using static.

Comment: If I get it right that would involve loading a complete new html-document with the template in it. What I want is to replace only the content of the <nav>-element, using ajax. So, without loading a new document from the server.

Comment: Create a separate path in urls.py and server your template folder with it

Answer (score 0):

You can expose your template directory to be served as static files by adding this to your urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls.static import static

PATH = '/get-static-templates/'
ROOT = '/var/www/html/templates/'

urlpatterns = [
    # ... the rest of your URLconf goes here ...
] + static(PATH, document_root=ROOT)
```

Here PATH is the url path i.e. `localhost:8000/get-static-template/` and ROOT is the absolute path of the folder you want to serve.